# Solve space between columns of three sliders (DIVI)

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, slider

I use DIVI/Wordpress.
How can I reduce the space between columns of my 3 slider? http://iconsmgmt.com/
Also, what code should I use to maintain the format of the slider on mobile devices? (the three slider in a row and not one below the other).
thank you!

http://iconsmgmt.com/

Comment: I am a lady. Maybe that's why I dont see 3 sliders in your link. Just a picture

Comment: try now please...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the mobile view try

```
@media (max-width: 980px)
.et_pb_column {
    width: 33%;
}
```

then you have to play with media queries. I don't know how much experience you have with css

Comment: have some experience. However, .et_pb_column didn't work for me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

try to add into your css

```
.et_pb_slide {
    padding: 0 2%;
}
```

It is 6% at the moment.

Comment: fantastic! thank you! One more...How to keep that design in mobile? (not responsive slider)

Comment: can you upvote my answer? I had a look on your mobile problem, but I didnt see any pics. Im guessing you are working on this right now? Ill have a look again

Comment: How do I vote your answer?
I do not understand why you do not see the slider on mobile, nothing I touched. Any ideas?

Comment: you just need to press the up icon next to my answer. I don't know, I see your pics when i resize the screen a little, but not when I go quite a bit down. It is probably your theme that is hiding them on small devices.